# Can I clone a github repo with the PR code "virtually" merged

Tags: git, github, git-merge

Here's the scenario:

I own a github repo. Someone creates and submits a PR. There are no merge conflicts. I want to clone the "end result" of the PR and my repo for testing purposes.

Is that possible? I know I can clone the PR repo and branch, but there is no guarantee that what I'm cloning is the actual PR request (they might have made additional changes after submitting the PR).

Basically, looking at the code itself in GitHub isn't good enough -- I need to run and test it locally, on my machine. How do I do that?

Thanks,
Vladimir

Comment: Make another repo (possibly even a dedicated user) specifically to test this Github tool you're building, test on that. Then there's no outside interference. You can do whatever you want to the repo, including blowing it away and recreating it every test to ensure the tests are isolated and it's in a known good state. And you don't have to put a production API code into your tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply  clone the PR repo and branch. Any change done in the branch off which PR was raised is automatically reflected in PR.

In the GitHub PR page, it says that the author of the PR can add more commits by pushing to the branch on his/her fork

Comment: that's what I want to avoid: "Any change done in the branch off which PR was raised is automatically reflected in PR."

Comment: When you clone the PR repo (or just fetch the remote branch), you will get a snapshot. That won't be updated unless you fetch again.

Comment: Right, but I won't know that what I'll be merging from github is what I tested locally unless I do another git pull...just was looking for a way to lock down the version

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to clone — just use branches. Commit the current work, create a new branch, switch to that branch, pull PR commits to you local repo (PR is just a branch too), run tests. If everything is ok — switch back to development branch, remove test branch, merge PR at Github and pull.

Example. Let's say the current branch is master, and you want to test Pull Request #42. Commit the current work and create a branch:
`git checkout -b test-42`. Pull and merge the PR: `git pull origin pull/42/head`. Run tests. Switch back to master and remove test branch:

```
git checkout master
git branch -D test-42
```

Merge the pull request at Github and pull: `git pull origin master`.